# Can I use kubernetes as service discovery in spring cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

May I ask if it is possible that I will use kubernetes in spring cloud instead of Eureka server?
The reason I am asking is we already have Kubernetes in our environment, I know Kubernete also provide service discovery, so I don't want to start Eureka server for service discovery purpose. If I can replace Eureka with Kubernete, that will be great.

Comment: Not yet https://github.com/spencergibb/spring-cloud-kubernetes

Comment: @spencergibb, thank you for sharing the git repo. May I ask if Spring cloud plan to replace Eureka with Kubernete in the near future as native service discovery solution?If so, any time line? I want to know because I need to decide if I need to change to kubernetes myself. I hope to see native support of Kubernetes in Spring Cloud

Comment: spring-cloud will never replace eureka, but it will offer alternatives like spring-cloud-consul and spring-cloud-zookeeper (they are in milestone releases, release candidate shortly).

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know

Comment: I also want to know could K8S service replace eureka-server or not.

Answer (score 1):

How about spring-cloud-kubernetes by fabric8io?

There is an implementation of the DiscoveryService interface to work with Kubernetes services.